# Como apagar todos as linhas comentadas no VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, comentários

Gostaria de saber se tem alguma forma de apagar todas as linhas comentadas (comentários) de uma só vez no Visual Studio Code? Por exemplo, tenho um arquivo `CSS` enorme com muitos comentários em meio ao código, gostaria de removê-los ao mesmo tempo, se possível...

Comment: Por padrão não há como apagar direto só com o VSCode. Porém há uma extensão que possibilita essa tarefa. Segue o link da extensão:
[https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=plibither8.remove-comments](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=plibither8.remove-comments)

Comment: Eu não sei se no VS Code tem find/replace com regex, mas no Notepad++ tu poderias fazer isso usando regex no find/replace...